# dataflow allocated too much disk space

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am running a dataflow job scaling from 40 workers to more, the job is taking 9.77 TB persistent disk storage now and hit the following error.

```
Autoscaling: Unable to reach resize target in zone us-central1-c. QUOTA_EXCEEDED: 
Quota 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' exceeded. Limit: 10240.0 in region us-central1.
```

The job shouldn't emit that much data as the result. So I am wondering what is the role of PD allocated in this case. Also how is it estimated for each worker?

Here's the dataflow job link: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/jobsDetail/locations/us-central1/jobs/2018-06-24_11_41_19-5444495474275650044?project=wikidetox&angularJsUrl=%2Fdataflow%2FjobsDetail%2Flocations%2Fus-central1%2Fjobs%2F2018-06-24_11_41_19-5444495474275650044%3Fproject%3Dwikidetox&authuser=1

Thank you, 
Yiqing

Answer (score 0):

The `DISKS_TOTAL_GB` quota is for hard drives allocated to your job, not for data emitted by it.

Is this a streaming job? I believe streaming jobs use pretty large hard drives to persist data about job execution. You can increase the `DISK_TOTAL_GB` quota for that project / zone, and you should be fine.

Comment: Just to add a little more information: according to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#persistent-disk-resources), there has to be at least one persistent disk per worker. By default the size of each persistent disk will be 400GB in streaming mode.